# Queueing writes to file system on Linux?

Tags: linux, io

On a very large SMP machine with many CPUS scripts are run with tens of simultaneous jobs (fewer than the number of CPUs) like this:

```
some_program -in FIFO1 >OUTPUT1 2>s_p1.log </dev/null &
some_program -in FIFO2 >OUTPUT2 2>s_p2.log </dev/null &
...
some_program -in FIFO40 >OUTPUT40 2>s_p40.log </dev/null &
splitter_program -in real_input.dat -out FIFO1,FIFO2...FIFO40
```

The splitter reads the input data flat out and distributes it to the FIFOs in order.  (Records 1,41,81... to FIFO1; 2,42,82 to FIFO2, etc.)  The splitter has low overhead and can pretty much process data as fast as the file system can supply it.

Each some_program processes its stream and writes it to its output file.  However, nothing controls the order in which the file system sees these writes. The writes are also very small, on the order of 10 bytes. The script "knows" that there are 40 streams here and that they could be buffered in 20M (or whatever) chunks, and then each chunk written to the file system sequentially.  That is, queued writes should be used to maximize write speed to the disks.  The OS, however, just sees a bunch of writes at about the same rate on each of the 40 streams.

What happens in practice during a run is that the subprocesses get a lot of CPU time (in top, >80%), then a flush process appears (10% CPU), and all the others drop to low CPU (1%), then it goes back to the higher rate.  These pauses go on for several seconds at a time.  The flush means that the writes are overwhelming the file caching.  Also I think the OS and/or the underlying RAID controller is probably bouncing the physical disk heads around erratically which is reducing the ultimate write speed to the physical disks.  That is just a guess though, since it is hard to say what exactly is happening as there is file cache (in a system with over 500Gb of RAM) and a RAID controller between the writes and the disk.

Is there a program or method around for controlling this sort of IO, forcing the file system writes to queue nicely to maximize write speed?

The "buffer" program is not going to help much here because, while it would accumulate an output stream into a big chunk, there wouldn't be an orderly queuing of the writes, so several could go out at the same time.  If the data rate in the output streams was uncorrelated this would be less of a problem, but in some cases the data rate is exactly the same in all streams, which means the buffers would all fill at the same time.  This would stall the entire tree until the last one was written because any process that cannot write an output will not reads its next input, and that would stall the splitter, as all I/O is synchronous.  The buffers need to be emptied in a cyclical manner, preferably before any of them completely fill up, although that may not be avoidable when data output rate exceeds the file system write rate.

There are dozens of parameters for tuning the file system, some of those might help.  The scheduler was changed from cfq to deadline because the system was locking up for minutes at a time with the former.

Comment: If your job is IO bound, parallelizing it across more cores will just make things worse. Especially when writing to HDDs. Have you tried just running fewer jobs?

Comment: Perhaps what you want is something that accumulates those 10-byte writes into memory-page or disk-block sized chunks (or even larger) and then *asynchronously* flushes them to disk, ie, goes ahead and continues accumulating a new chunk even while waiting for old ones to be committed to disk.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is sheer I/O bandwidth then buffering won't solve anything.  In that case, you need to shrink the data or send it to a higher-bandwidth sink to improve and level your performance.  One way to do that would be to reduce the number of parallel jobs, as @thatotherguy said.

If in fact the problem is with the number of distinct I/O operations rather than with the overall volume of data, however, then buffering might be a viable solution.  I am unfamiliar with the `buffer` program you mentioned, but I suppose it does what its name suggests.  I don't completely agree with your buffering comments, however:

> The "buffer" program is not going to help much here because, while it would accumulate an output stream into a big chunk, there wouldn't be an orderly queuing of the writes, so several could go out at the same time.

You don't necessarily need *big* chunks.  It would probably be ideal to chunk at the native block size of the file system, or a small integer multiple thereof.  That might be, say, 4096- or 8192-byte chunks.

Moreover, I don't see why you think you have an "orderly queueing of writes" now, or why you're confident that such a thing is needed.

> If the data rate in the output streams was uncorrelated this would be less of a problem, but in some cases the data rate is exactly the same in all streams, which means the buffers would all fill at the same time. This would stall the entire tree until the last one was written because any process that cannot write an output will not reads its next input, and that would stall the splitter, as all I/O is synchronous.

Your splitter is writing to FIFOs.  Though it may do so serially, that is not "synchronous" in the sense that the data needs to be drained out the other end before the splitter can proceed -- at least, not if the writes do not exceed the size of the FIFOs' buffers.  FIFO buffer capacity varies from system to system, adapts dynamically on some systems, and is configurable (e.g. via `fcntl()`) on some systems.  The default buffer size on modern Linux is 64kB.

> The buffers need to be emptied in a cyclical manner, preferably before any of them completely fill up, although that may not be avoidable when data output rate exceeds the file system write rate.

I think this is a problem that pretty much solves itself.  If one of the buffers backs up enough to block the splitter, then that ensures that the competing processes will, before too long, give the blocked buffer the opportunity to write.  But this is also why you don't want enormous buffers -- you want to interleave disk I/O from different processes relatively finely to try to keep everything going.

The alternative to an external buffer program is to modify your processes to perform internal buffering.  That might be an advantage because it removes a whole set of pipes (to an external buffering program) from the mix, and it lightens the process load on the machines.  It does mean modifying your working processing program, though, so perhaps it would be better to start with external buffering to see how well that does.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your 40 streams each have a high data rate, and your RAID controller cannot write to physical disk fast enough, then you need to redesign your disk system. Basically, divide it into 40 RAID-1 mirrors and write one file to each mirror set. That makes the writes sequential for each stream, but requires 80 disks.

If the data rate isn't the problem then you need to add more buffering. You might need a pair of threads. One thread to collect the data into memory buffers and another thread to write it into data files and fsync() it. To make the disk writes sequential it should fsync each output file one at a time. That should result in writing large sequential chunks of whatever your buffer size is. 8 MB maybe?